# como puedo recorrer un one2many y sumar la cantidad de productos que tengan el mismo id odoo versión 14

Tags: python, odoo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tengo dos productos iguales y luego escojo otros dos productos que tengan el mismo id como muestra en la imagen, la cantidad que les pertenece se deben sumar y guardar en una lista para luego dividirlo con la cantidad a mano cada resultado.

Logramos que solo se sumen solo los primeros dos productos, los otros dos iguales no los suma.

```py
for record in self:
  can = 0
  se = 0
  can1 = 0 
  id1 = 0
  id2 = 0
  p = True
  menor=999999
  list = []

  for cm in record.bom_line_ids: 
    # valida que tome la cantidad a mano de la primera fila si o si, lo 
     #hicimos así ya que no quería tomar la primera línea 
    if cm.x_studio_id_producto and p == True:
      record['x_studio_suma3_1'] = cm.x_studio_cantidad_a_mano
      p = False
      se = cm.x_studio_id_producto
     
      for e in record.bom_line_ids: 
       if e.x_studio_id_producto == se:
         id2 = se
         can = e.x_studio_cantidad_a_mano
       
      # valida con el id del producto si son iguales y asi sumalos
       if e.x_studio_id_producto == se:
         id1 = se
         can1 += e.product_qty
    
       elif id1 == id2:
         result = can / can1 if can1 else 0
         list.append(result)
         for numero in list:
            if numero<menor:
              menor=numero
              record['x_studio_suma3_1'] = menor
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. te recomiendo que agregues un [example] para que podamos reproducir tu problema y sea más fácil ayudarte. Deberías agregar el código de lo que intentaste hasta el momento. Te recomiendo también que hagas el [tour].

Comment: Hola! Lograste resolverlo? Puedes usar un diccionario donde la key sea el nombre id del producto. Si el id no está registrado, creas uno nuevo.